# Modify old MVC version DBContext format to .NET 6 format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have the following DBContext code in old MVC

```
public class APContext : DbContext
{
    public APContext() : base("name=APContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<APContext>(null);

        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public APContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, true) { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And use the following code to get the data:

```
public async Task<string> GetUsername(int userId)
{
    using (var ctx = new APContext())
    {
        var query = ctx.Users.Where(w => w.Id == userId).Select(x => x.Username);

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

And I tried modified the code to .NET 6 like below:

In appsetting.json:

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=testdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=admin;Password=abc;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

In my Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSqlServer<APContext>(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

In my APContext.cs file:

```
public class APContext : DbContext
{
    public APContext(DbContextOptions<APContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

How do I change the following code to .NET 6 version? my context value seem always get null. I wanna move the following method to new cs file instead of inside controller.

```
public async Task<string> GetUsername(int userId)
{
    using (var ctx = new APContext())
    {
        var query = ctx.Users.Where(w => w.Id == userId).Select(x => x.Username);

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike old versions, .NET Core supports dependency injection out of the box, so you don't need to create the instance of DbContext every time.

Here is the interface.

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    Task<string> GetUsername(int userId);
}
```

And the implementation.

```
public class UserRepository
{
    private readonly APContext _apContext;
    public UserRepository(APContext apContext)
    {
        _apContext = apContext
    }
    public async Task<string> GetUsername(int userId)
    {
         var query = _apContext.Users
            .Where(w => w.Id == userId).Select(x => x.Username);
         return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

So first you need to inject the DbContext like this - in Program.cs

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
builder.Services.AddDbContext<APContext>
    (options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository,UserRepository>();
```

Next you need to modify the controller or service constructor and add a parameter of `APContext` like this.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
}
```

And now in the method, you can do like this.

```
public async Task<string> GetUsername(int userId)
{
    return await _userRepository.GetUsername(userId);
}
```

You can use the connection string in the `OnModelCreating` method as well, I feel this is an approach.

Comment: Thanks for answer, how about if I wanna code by style like "using (var ctx = new APContext()) { }" ? _apContext as global variable will auto dispose the connection after return method? And how if I wanna move the GetUsername() method to another cs file instead of inside controller?

Comment: Ideally, you should be able to use it. But it is not the recommended method.

Comment: I see, then how if I wanna move the GetUsername() method to another cs file instead of inside controller?

Comment: You can create a repository class move the method there and inject it into the controller.

Comment: Can you please modify your code to show example how it work? Thanks